# Javascript append text at beginning and end of each string in a textarea

Tags: javascript

I need to add a `"` (Quote) to the beginning and a `"& _` (Quote ampersand and Underscore)  to the end of each line, within a Textarea, when a button is pressed.

**Example**

Before, the content of the textarea looks like this:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
etc...
```

After, the content of the textarea would look like this:

```
"This is line 1"& _
"This is line 2"& _
"etc..."& _
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: get textarea as string use "\n" split separator to get array and then prepend and append your cosmetic changes and join now try

Comment: Please include *the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem*, which should minimally include some JavaScript considering your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split your textarea content by `\n` and do the desired editing and you can then join them back using `join()` function in javascript.

Set this value back to the textarea.

**Sample Code**

```js
function foo() {
  var str = document.getElementById("test").value;
  var lines = str.split("\n");
  for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    lines[i] = "\"" + lines[i] + "\"& _";
  }
  document.getElementById("test").value = lines.join("\n");
}
```

```html
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
<button onclick="foo()">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Perfect! Sorry, I was not able to get back and post what I was trying, the issue was. I could not find anything that would work. Everything that I found was only doing 1 line, not multiple lines like what was needed. Like what you provided here. I had been looking for a few hours and only found about three codes to test, but all just did one line. Thank you RSR!!! You Rock!

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="txtString"></textarea>
    <script>
        var txtString = $("#txtString");
        txtString = str.split("\n");
        var afterString = '';
        for (var i =0; i = txtString.length; i++) {
            afterString += '"'+txtString[i]+'"& _';
        }
        $("#txtString").val(afterString);
</script>
```

Hope u want this type something.. Enjoy :)